# Ruby on Ruby records redundant rows with same ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have been facing one serious issue in Ruby on Rails code for quite a long time. The active record records the transactions redundantly sometimes upto 3 times but this doesn't happen to all users. Let's say out of 100 upto 3 are affected. Surprisingly since i am using timestamp to save transaction ids all redundant rows often are recorded with the same id not even a difference of single second between all of them.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
before_action :restrict_access, except: [:authenticate, :go_success, :go_failed]

def creategoal
  goal =  @user_info.goal.create(days: 365)
  if goal.save
    goal.goals_mandates.create(reference: "000-000-GG-#{goal.id}",
                               price_dd: params[:amount],
                               mandate_attempt_date: Date.today,
                               mandate_active: false)
    self.initTrans(goal)
  end
end

def initTrans(goal)
  userType = UserType.where(name: "partner").first
  if userType.user_info_types.where(user_info_id: @user.id).first.nil?
    @user.user_info_types.create(user_type_id: userType.id) 
  end
  transaction_id = "GG-"+ Time.now.to_i.to_s
  transaction = goal.goal_transaction.create(batch_id: transaction_id,
                                             response_batch: transaction_id,
                                             amount_deducted: session[:amount_to_save], 
                                             transaction_type: "direct_debit", 
                                             merchant: @accessor.name)
  if transaction.save
    redirect_to "/success?trans_id="+transaction_id
  else
    redirect_to "/failed"
  end
end
```

I will be grateful if anyone genius out there can help me out.

Comment: A second can be an eternity in a CPU.  Don't make your own unique ids -- use a UUID.

Comment: @dbugger thanks for suggestion. but can you also help me out with the main problem?

Comment: That is the main problem.

Comment: E.g., with one-second resolution it's easy to get duplicate values--a lot can happen in a second. It is insufficiently unique. This isn't surprising; even under moderate load one second is a long time. The IDs should be *guaranteed* unique, e.g., a UUID. You can still *store* a timestamp, because that has value, but it shouldn't be used as an ID *on its own*. You could *add* information to the timestamp, e.g., a user ID or a session ID (although this won't help if a single user has multiple tabs and is running duplicate processes), but UUID is better.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks. Actually i am not using timestamp as unique identifier for the transactions. It is a substitute. Even in other method for other function of app. Sometimes i am also getting duplicates for users. The commonality between this code which i have shared and the other one is i am using self.method alot in them. Do you think i am not using a proper way of defining a method inside a method that is what cause the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "defining a method inside a method", no code here does that, and if they're all instance methods, or all class methods, `self.` is generally redundant (with some exceptions).

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "getting duplicates for users" since there's no user creation here. Also not sure what a `goal_mandate` "reference" is for since you already have a goal ID if it's a proper relationship. Ultimately it's not very clear what the issue is.

Comment: Actually goals table has 1 - Many relationship with goals_mandates table when i meant defining i actually meant calling an instance method from another instance method using self. "getting duplicates for users" i meant by their transactions. Like sometimes only i get duplicate rows. I even check logs found that method initTrans method called multiple times thus leads to duplicate rows for transactions sometimes.

Comment: If you're able to reproduce the behavior in a development environment then you might find the https://github.com/brunofacca/active-record-query-trace gem useful in helping to trace exactly which line in the code base executed a SQL insert statement